# Making QListWidget resize its items to fill space

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidget

I've got a QListWidget and I've got a custom widget class, which I'm creating an instance of for each item appearing in the list widget.

But I can't figure out how to make my custom widget expand to fill all the available space of each row in the list widget.

My custom widget is created in Qt Designer, and I've set its size hint to be expanding horizontally, but it doesn't do this when placed in my list widget (i.e. in designer, the widget is set to be say, 200px wide. The list widget is actually 400px wide, but my custom widget in each row does not expand to fill this space...)

How do I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're putting items in here using QListWidget::setItemWidget()?

If that's the case, then you usually need to set the sizeHint() of your QListWidgetItem to that of your custom widget:

```
myListWidget->setItemWidget( myListWidgetItem, customWidget );
myListWidgetItem->setSizeHint( customWidget->sizeHint() );
```

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing. When I set my `listWidgetItem`'s sizeHint, however, to the sizeHint of my custom widget, I end up with no row at all (I'm assuming it gets set to 0, 0 or something).. I've probably got the sizeHint set up incorrect for my custom widget... The policy is set to expanding, though.. thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.  Normally the default size policy (which I believe is preferred/preferred) is good enough for your top-level widget in designer.  Without delving into the UI file and implemenatation I'm not what else the issue could be.

Comment: Did you figure out what your problem was?

Answer (score 1):

As an update, since Qt 5.2. you can set the `QListWidget`'s `sizeAdjustPolicy`:

`listWidget-setSizeAdjustPolicy(QListWidget::AdjustToContents);`

This would resize the QListWidget every time a new item is added to it (whose width exceeds the current width).

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop